# Design Decision -- How to handle ImageList in a Game for good memory management

Tags: c#, image

I am in the process of building a game.

I have an object GamePiece (there will also be a Card Deck also)

```
public enum PieceColor
{
    Blue=0,
    Yellow,
    Red,
    Green
}

public class GamePiece : PictureBox
{
    PieceColor _color;
    public PieceColor Color {
        get {

            return _color;
        }
        set
        {
            _color = value;

            if (_color == PieceColor.Blue)
                this.Image = global::GameEntities.Properties.Resources.pieceBlue;
        }
    }
```

What I was thinking is putting four images, one of each color into a ImageList then the above line can be changed to

```
  this.Image = ImageList[(int)_color];
```

The problem I foresee with this is that I would be creating a ImageList for every GamePiece and that is a strain on memory.

A couple options would be

- Create a Static Class of ImageList objects, then have all pieces reference that static class
- Create one resource bitmap with all 4 pieces on it as one image, then use size manipulation to just show the one piece
- Leave the code the way it is and just have four different IF statements

So my questions are,

- Is one solution preferred over the other when it comes to managing memory with the same images used over and over?
- Is there any Design Patterns when it comes to display images, or any other related Game Concepts that I could study up on?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create a singleton class that stores your images and create getImage method that takes in a color and returns the image icon.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it was the direction I was thinking, but after googling there are two recommendations never to use singleton but I am not absolutely sure why [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/what-are-some-programming-design-patterns-that-are-useful-in-game-development) and
[Design_Patterns_in_Game_Programming](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/MichaelHaney/20110920/90250/Design_Patterns_in_Game_Programming.php) and
[gameprogrammingpatterns](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/singleton.html)

Comment: In the case you mentioned above, the use of singleton solves most of your problems because in your entire game, you will have only 4 types of game pieces (defined by color) .... It doesn't matter how many instance of the GamePiece class you create, it will only have one of the color type. Your singleton is just a wrapper around the physical files and you are exposing them out via properties.

Comment: So I tried this over the weekend and either it is not working or I don't understand what it is accomplishing.  I thought since I have a singleton reference if I do `piece.Image = Resouce.Instance.GetColor(blue)` and the GetColor just points to `return ImageList[0]` that multiple blue pieces would point to one image reference.  But I know this not to be true because if I change `Imagelist[0]= differentImage`all the pieces Images are not updated, which tells me that they are not all pointing to the same reference.  Does that make sense?

Comment: When you do the piece.Image = Resouce.Instance.GetColor(blue) it holds the resource in the "piece" object. So even if you change the other objects they won't impact this one. So you want a solution where if you change one typed piece then all other similar pieces change as well?

Comment: I am thinking of c++ style pointers.  In an effort to save memory all pieces should be pointing to one BitMap.  Instead of each piece holding a copy of the resource.  Seems redundant and inefficient.  Hope that clears it up.

Comment: In that case, you should better off with creating a static class and load your images from there.